# In a number field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $\alpha$ integer on $\mathbb{Q},$ root of a p-Eisenstein polynomial: p doesn’t divide the index

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $\alpha$ integer on $\mathbb{Q}.$ If $\alpha$ is a root of a p-Eisenstein polynomial, then p doesn’t divide the index

I want to prove what I have written in the title. So let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ the number field. I tried to prove this fact as follows:
I know that
$$ind(\alpha)=|\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]|.$$
Let $p$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha:$ $p(x)=c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n,$ where the coefficients are integers, $p$ divide all of them and $p^2$ does not divide $c_0.$
Since $\alpha$ is an integer, I know that
$$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=(1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots,\alpha^{n-1})_\mathbb{Z}$$
and there exists integers $a_i$ such that
$$\mathcal{O}_K=(1,b_1\alpha,b_2\alpha^2,\dots,b_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1})_\mathbb{Z}$$
Then
$$\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Z}/b_1\mathbb{Z}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}/b_{n-1}\mathbb{Z},$$
$$ind(\alpha)=b_1\cdot\dots\cdot b_{n-1}$$
If $p$ divides the index, then it divides at least one of the $b_i.$
I would like to conclude using the fact that $b_i\alpha$ is an integer, but I don’t see how. Is my way a good way for proving this fact? How can I conclude?

Comment: For future questions, it’s generally considered best to repeat the question in the text. This allows you to make explicit the setting and all hypotheses that are part of the situation. And while I’m at it, let me ask, on behalf of all other geezers and crones with failing vision, that you not use both letters $a$ and $\alpha$ in the same presentation.

Comment: See Theorem 2.3 in [these](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf) notes of Keith Conrad.